# Acrobat Function MenuItemExecute("DIGSIG:CompareDocuments") not working in server

Tags: wcf, pdf, compare, acrobat, documents

Someone has any idea why the function MenuItemExecute("DIGSIG:CompareDocuments") wouldn't work when running on a WCF web service deployed in a server?

when I run it locally it runs just fine, does the job it is supposed to do. But when I deploy the app into a server, it gets 'stuck' in this call .

Anyone has any idea what could possibly be wrong?

In both machines, local and server I have Adobe XI Pro installed.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running Acrobat on the server? Note that Acrobat is neither technically nor legally able/allowed to run on a server (as a service).

Comment: Yeah, @MaxWyss I found that:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8057317#8057317

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be looking at the same issue, as stated before this cannot happen.

Acrobat cannot be used in a web service, but it can and will run on a Server unlike what someone from Acrobat staff said:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8057317#8057317